# Calculating the number of maximum repetitive character in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, count

I am looking for a way to find out the value of maximum character repetition in a string.

For instance :

```
 String         NMCR
-----------------------
akhsdjjjaajjj    6   
AABBDDDDDDD      7
```

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "maximum character repetition" since it's not clear in your example.

Comment: @TomH i think he meant how many times a character repeat it self in the same string > 'A' in 'analytic' -> 2

Comment: Its not often that a question here returns four totally different and really interesting ways to solve a problem. This one did, and makes me want to benchmark them all as now curious on how they all perform! This is the sort of question / answer set that keeps me coming here because I still learn something Oracle every day. Kudos to all involved.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton It is astonishing. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An odd requirement, but here is a way:

```
create or replace
function max_repetetive_letter_count (string varchar2) return integer 
is
   letter_col SYS.KU$_VCNT := SYS.KU$_VCNT(); -- A handy collection type
   l_max_count integer;
begin
   letter_col.extend(length(string));

   for i in 1..length(string) loop
      letter_col(i) := substr(string,i,1);
   end loop;

   select max(letter_count) 
   into   l_max_count
   from
   ( select column_value, count(*) letter_count
     from   table(letter_col)
     group by column_value
   );

   return l_max_count;
end;
/
```

Example usage:

```
SQL> select string, max_repetetive_letter_count(string)
  2  from 
  3  ( select 'ajkhsdjjjaajjj' as string from dual
  4    union all
  5    select 'AABBDDDDDDD' as string from dual
  6  );

STRING         MAX_REPETETIVE_LETTER_COUNT(STRING)
-------------- -----------------------------------
ajkhsdjjjaajjj                                   7
AABBDDDDDDD                                      7
```

(NB The 6 in your example was incorrect!)

Comment: Thanks Buddy, do you think we can execute this query on a dataset including 60 million rows?

Comment: Yes but it won't be quick as it will involve 60M context switches as the function is called for each row.  It would be interesting to compare with @Florin's answer, since that includes no PL/SQL (and no regexp stuff either!)

Comment: I will execute both and share the result. Thank you Guys!

Comment: @TonyAndrews I think your answer is more flexible, just adding a parallel_enable and some pragma restrict references it would run in parallel. Also, if the texts repeats it would be nice to add a deterministic clause(And my code to be changed :) )

Answer (score 7):

My try, with steps highlighted by CTEs:

```
 with data as (select 'akhsdjjjaajjj' txt from dual
               union all
               select 'AABBDDDDDDD' txt from dual
               ),  
      chars as(select txt,substr(txt,lvl, 1) c, lvl
            from data join (select level lvl from dual connect by level < 1000) 
              on length(data.txt) >= lvl
              ),  
      counts as (select txt, c, count(*) cnt
            from chars
            group by txt, c
            )  
select txt, max(cnt)  
from counts  
group by txt;
```

Result:

> TXT   MAX(CNT)
>
> akhsdjjjaajjj 6
>
> AABBDDDDDDD   7

Comment: For speed you should replace 1000 with maximum length of the strings.

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use `connect by` clause:

```
SELECT cad,
       (    SELECT MAX (REGEXP_COUNT (cad, SUBSTR (cad, LEVEL, 1)))
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < LENGTH (cad))
  FROM (SELECT 'akhsdjjjaajjj' cad FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'AABBDDDDDDD' FROM DUAL)
```

I hope this helps too.

Comment: This is very computational but it has the advantage that it can run with parallel clause.

Comment: Yes @FlorinGhita , using parallelism will be faster. That's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the original version of the question (counting only repeated characters):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( id, string ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ajkhsdjjjaajjj' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'AABBDDDDDDD' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       matched_character,
       frequency
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         matched_character,
         SUM( number_of_repeats ) AS frequency,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUM( number_of_repeats ) DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   (       
    SELECT id,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, '(.)\1+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE, NULL, 1 ) AS matched_character,
           LENGTH( REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, '(.)\1+', 1, COLUMN_VALUE ) ) AS number_of_repeats
    FROM   test t,
           TABLE(
             CAST(
               MULTISET(
                 SELECT LEVEL
                 FROM   DUAL
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.string, '(.)\1+' )
                )
                AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
              )
            ) v
  )
  GROUP BY id, matched_character
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

**Results**:

```
 ID MATCHED_CHARACTER   FREQUENCY
--- ------------------ ----------
  1 j                           6 
  2 D                           7
```

**Updated - for the edited question (counting all characters)**:

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       matched_character,
       frequency
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         SUBSTR( string, COLUMN_VALUE, 1 ) AS matched_character,
         COUNT(1) AS frequency,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC ) AS rnk
  FROM   test t,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT LEVEL
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( t.string )
              )
              AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
            )
          ) v
  GROUP BY id, SUBSTR( string, COLUMN_VALUE, 1 )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

**Results**:

```
        ID MATCHED_CHARACTER  FREQUENCY
---------- ----------------- ----------
         1 j                          7 
         2 D                          7
```